# How to use nsITimer in a Firefox Extension?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, settimeout, setinterval, firefox4

I am working on a Firefox extension, and wish to make use of a timer to control posting of data every 60 seconds.

The following is placed inside an initialization function in the main .js file:

```
var timer = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/timer;1"].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsITimer);
timer.init(sendResults(true), 60000, 1);
```

However, when I try to run this I get the following error in the Firefox console:

```
"Component returned failure code: 0x80004003 (NS_ERROR_INVALID_POINTER) [nsITimer.init]" nsresult: "0x80004003"...
```

And so on. What did I do wrong?

### **UPDATE**:

The following works for my needs, although the initial problem of using nsITimer instead still remains:

var interval = window.setInterval(function(thisObj) { thisObj.sendResults(true); }, 1000, this);
   }

Useful links that explain why this works (documentation on setInterval/sendResults, as well as solution to the 'this' problem:

https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/window.setTimeout
https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Window.setInterval (won't let me post more than two hyperlinks)

http://klevo.sk/javascript/javascripts-settimeout-and-how-to-use-it-with-your-methods/

Comment: Any reason you're not using `setTimeout` or `setInterval`?

Comment: @Pat: Not particularly - nsITimer seemed to be a better solution to have a repeating timer, something which seemed more messy to do with setTimeout/setInterval especially since I run into problems when trying to use 'this'.

Comment: @Pat: I tried using setInterval again and got it to work. Updating the question with my solution using setInterval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nsITimer.init()` takes an observer as first parameter. You probably want to use a callback instead:

```
timer.initWithCallback(function() {sendResults(true); }, 60000, Components.interfaces.nsITimer.TYPE_REPEATING_SLACK);
```

But `window.setInterval()` is easier to use nevertheless - if you have a window that won't go away (closing a window removes all intervals and timeouts associated with it).